# Disable a Button

Tags: swift, uibutton, ios8

I want to disable a button (`UIButton`) on iOS after it is clicked. I am new to developing for iOS but I think the equivalent code on objective - C is this:

```
button.enabled = NO;
```

But I couldn't do that on swift.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

The boolean value for `NO` in Swift is `false`.

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

should do it.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618217-isenabled) is the Swift documentation for `UIControl`'s `isEnabled` property.

Comment: It's the same whether you created the button via its initializer or via storyboards.

Comment: I meant when I have no outlet. Anyhow the solution is to define the button globally.

Answer (score 49):

If you want the button to stay static without the "pressed" appearance:

```
// Swift 2
editButton.userInteractionEnabled = false 

// Swift 3
editButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

---

Remember:

1) Your `IBOutlet` is --> `@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!`

2) Code above goes in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: I thought this was exactly what I was looking for, but this appears to be UIKit only, not AppKit.

Answer (score 14):

The way I do this is as follows:

```
@IBAction func pressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var disableMyButton = sender as? UIButton
    disableMyButton.enabled = false
}
```

The IBAction is connected to your button in the storyboard.

If you have your button setup as an Outlet:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
```

Then you can access the enabled properties by using the . notation on the button name:

```
    myButton.enabled = false
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Swift 4. I noticed by default it sets the sender to Any instead of AnyObject but both still work.... What error are you getting?

Comment: For clarity, perhaps you should state in your answer above that the IBOutlet is required for your code to work. Whether or not the IBOutlet was needed is what confused me. Clearly, it is needed.

Comment: It's not required for it to work. You can type cast the button in the IBAction and change the enabled status or if you have it set up as an IBOutlet you can do it using the .notation on the outlet. Both ways work.

Comment: I do believe that the IBOutlet is needed if you are to disable the button from within another function.

Answer (score 8):

Disable a button on Swift 3:

```
yourButton.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 8):

For those who Googled "disable a button" but may have more nuanced use cases:

**Disable with visual effect:** As others have said, this will prevent the button from being pressed and the system will automatically make it look disabled:

```
yourButton.isEnabled = false
```

**Disable without visual effect:** Are you using a button in a case where it should look normal but not behave likes button by reacting to touches? Try this!

```
yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

**Hide without disabling:** This approach hides the button without disabling it (invisible but can still be tapped):

```
 yourButton.alpha = 0.0
```

**Remove:** This will remove the view entirely:

```
 yourButton.removeFromSuperView()
```

**Tap something behind a button:** Have two buttons stacked and you want the top button to temporarily act like it's not there? If you won't need the top button again, remove it. If you will need it again, try condensing its height or width to 0!

Answer (score 5):

### Swift 5 / SwiftUI

Nowadays it's done like this.

```
Button(action: action) {
  Text(buttonLabel)
}
  .disabled(!isEnabled)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enable/disable a button using `isEnabled` or `isUserInteractionEnabled` property.

The difference between two is :

- `isEnabled` is a property of UIControl (super class of UIButton) and it **has visual effects (i.e. grayed out)** of enable/disable
- `isUserInteractionEnabled` is a property of UIView (super class of UIControl) and has no visual effect although but achieves the purpose

**Usage :**

```
myButton.isEnabled = false // Recommended approach

myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false // Alternative approach
```

Comment: Do you know why I am getting this error? `Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member 'isEnabled'`

Comment: I also get an error if I change `(_ sender: )` to `UIButton` . The error reads: `Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'isEnabled'`

Answer (score 0):

The button can be Disabled in Swift 4 by the code

```
@IBAction func yourButtonMethodname(sender: UIButon) {
 yourButton.isEnabled = false 
}
```

Comment: If you try your code this error should occur: `Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member 'isEnabled'`

Comment: I think you mean `yourButton(sender: UIButton)`. Your updated code will likely cause the following error: `Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'isEnabled'`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say in Swift 4 you have a button set up for a segue as an `IBAction` like this `@IBAction func nextLevel(_ sender: UIButton) {}`
and you have other actions occurring within your app (i.e. a timer, gamePlay, etc.). Rather than disabling the segue button, you might want to give your user the option to use that segue while the other actions are still occurring and **WITHOUT CRASHING THE APP**. Here's how:

```
var appMode = 0

@IBAction func mySegue(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if appMode == 1 {  // avoid crash if button pressed during other app actions and/or conditions
        let conflictingAction = sender as UIButton
        conflictingAction.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Please note that you will likely have other conditions within `if appMode == 0` and/or `if appMode == 1` that will still occur and NOT conflict with the `mySegue` button. Thus, **AVOIDING A CRASH**.

Answer (score 0):

in order for this to work:

```
yourButton.isEnabled = false
```

you need to create an outlet in addition to your UI button.

Answer (score 0):

Building on other answers here.  I wanted to disable button for a few seconds to prevent double taps.  Swift 5 version, xcode 13.4.1 likes this and has no warnings or errors.

```
@IBAction func saveComponent(_ sender: Any) {
  let myButton = sender as? UIButton
  myButton?.isEnabled = false
    
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(2000)) 
  {
    myButton?.isEnabled = true
  }
}
```