# UIButton selected state and store value

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I'm new in iOS Development, I have a problem to make two button selected and unselected state and then store value of a gender. I want when user choose gender the other gender will be disable. Can anyone help me?

My button code

```
let menButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Men", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .yellow
    button.isSelected = false
    button.isEnable = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePickGender), for: .touchUpInside
    return button
}()

let womenButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Women", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.isSelected = false
    button.isEnable = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePickGender), for: .touchUpInside
    return button
}()
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524638/disable-a-button

Comment: By making a button disabled, do you mean to say that you need to update the color or text of the buttons to **show** this change, while the button that's not selected should still be available for selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@objc func handlePickGender(sender: UIButton) {
        menButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.yellow, for: .normal)
        womenButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.yellow, for: .normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        //store gender
        let selectedGender = sender.title(for: .normal)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create `enum` for Gender and add the Male and Female as the cases for that `enum`.

```
enum Gender {
  case male
  case female
 }
```

Have the switch for toggling the `UIButton` states.

```
func chooseGender(_ gender: Gender) {

   switch gender {
     case .male:
        // code for select and unselect
     case .female:
        // code for select and unselect
    }
}
```

From the `UIButton`, use the `isEnabled` property for enable and disable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create toggle buttons.

you can set button image for state.

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "unselected"), for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected"), for: .selected)


@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    button.selected = !button.selected
}
```

OR you can set background color for button

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        button.selected = !button.selected
        if button.selected {
             button.backgroundColor = .blue
        } else {
             button.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
}
```